# v4l2 fcntl.ioctl VIDIOC_S_PARM for setting fps and resolution of camera capture

Tags: python, webcam, v4l2

I am trying to set fps and resolution of webcam and capture from it via v4l2 Python.

v4l2 Python documentation is limited to ;

```
>>> import v4l2
>>> import fcntl
>>> vd = open('/dev/video0', 'rw')
>>> cp = v4l2.v4l2_capability()
>>> fcntl.ioctl(vd, v4l2.VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, cp)
0
>>> cp.driver
'ov534'
>>> cp.card
'USB Camera-B4.09.24.1'
```

Looking at the videodev2.h ;

```
#define VIDIOC_S_PARM       _IOWR('V', 22, struct v4l2_streamparm)
```

VIDIOC_S_PARM is related to v4l2_streamparm that is ;

```
struct v4l2_streamparm {
    enum v4l2_buf_type type;
union {
    struct v4l2_captureparm capture;
    struct v4l2_outputparm  output;
    __u8    raw_data[200];  /* user-defined */
} parm;
};
```

And if I want to set the parameter ;

```
import v4l2
import fcntl
vd = open('/dev/video1', 'rw')
cp = v4l2.v4l2_streamparm()
fcntl.ioctl(vd, v4l2.v4l2_streamparm, cp)
```

this is as far as I could get.

How can I adjust fps rate and resolution of the camera using Python v4l2 and capture images from it ?

Comment: your `fcntl.ioctl()` invocation is not correct, you need to use `fcntl.ioctl(vd, v4l2.VIDIOC_S_PARM, cp)` after suitably modifying `cp` (a `v4l2.v4l2_streamparm` as you've found).

Comment: `fcntl.ioctl(vd, v4l2.VIDIOC_S_PARM, cp)` resulted in Error no 22 invalid argument.

Comment: If you have done what I called _suitably modifying_ `cp` then please post your code; otherwise, the set params ioctl will give `EINVAL` simply because the request isn't initialized and contains garbage. See my answer below for how the structure needs to be set up.

Answer (score 5):

From the V4L2 side, you need to:

- use the [`VIDIOC_G_PARM`](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/vidioc-g-parm.html) ioctl and check the `v4l2_streamparm.parm.capture.capability` member to find out whether the driver allows `V4L2_CAP_TIMEPERFRAME`.
- if so, use the [`VIDIOC_ENUM_FRAMEINTERVALS`](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/vidioc-enum-frameintervals.html) ioctl to get the list of possible frame intervals (inverse of framerates), in the form of [`v4l2_fract`](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/vidioc-enumstd.html#v4l2-fract) structures
- use these values with the [`VIDIOC_S_PARM`](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/vidioc-g-parm.html) ioctl and fill in the `v4l2_streamparm.parm.capture.timeperframe` member.

That should allow setting the capture-side frame rate. It's your task to make sure you're reading fast enough not to get frame drops.